# Array of IBAction

Tags: objective-c, arrays, methods, ibaction

```
- (IBAction)buyHouse[6]:(id)sender;
```

I want to make an array of `IBActions` by doing what is shown above. It didn't allow me. Is it possible to make an array of method so as that if I want to implement it, I just need to do this.

```
 - (IBAction)buyHouse[3]:(id)sender{
   _Price.text = [NSString formatWithString: @"hello"];
}
```

This `IBAction` is for many `UIButton`.

This is my first ever question, so I am truly sorry if it's vague. I'm quite new to Objective-C and this community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as Objective-C is so dynamic, you can call a method just by knowing its name:

MyClass.m:

```
static NSArray *_methods = nil;

@implementation MyClass

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if (!_methods) {
            _methods = @[
                @"method1:",
                @"method2:",
                @"method3:"
            ];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)callMethod:(NSUInteger)index forSender:(id)sender
{
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(_methods[index]);
    [self performSelector:selector withObject:sender];
}

- (IBAction)method1:(id)sender
{

}

// etc.
```

Comment: After running, Static NSArray seem to have problem due to the "@" in front of the "[ @"method1....];". It said, "Initializer element is not compile-time constant." I tried putting it everywhere, in the implementation, inside the Method, and even outside (as you did).

Comment: @Learner I often get tripped-up on what is and is not a compile-time constant.  I have editted the code and that should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use blocks instead of methods.

Handy typedef for a block which matches an IBAction signature.  Not used in this example.

```
typedef void(^IBActionBlock)(id sender);
```

Define your array of actions.  Each entry in the array is a block which takes a single object as a parameter.

```
NSArray *ibActions = @[
                       ^(id sender) {
                           // 0
                       },
                       ^(id sender) {
                           // 1
                       },
                       ^(id sender) {
                           // 2
                       },
                       ^(id sender) {
                           // 3
                       },
                       ^(id sender) {
                           // 4
                       },
                       ^(id sender) {
                           // 5
                       },
                      ];
```

Example call site.

```
ibActions[2](button);
```

Answer (score 0):

### you can do this with tags and by taking advantage of performSelector:

1. you'd assign tags to the buttons [you can do so in IB. that'd be the index]
2. you'd have ONE IBAction called `buyHouseByTag` and then you'd connect all buttons to that one method
3. you'd have buyHouse1, buyHouse2 ....

---

#### buyHouseByTag is your proxy:

```
- (IBAction)buyHouseByTag:(id)sender {
    NSInteger index = [sender tag];
    NSString *method = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"buyHouse%d:", index];
    SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(method)
    [self performSelector:sel withObject:sender];
}

- (IBAction)buyHouse0:(id)sender {
}
- (IBAction)buyHouse1:(id)sender {
}
- (IBAction)buyHouse2:(id)sender {
}
```

Comment: What does: "SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(method)
    [self performSelector:sel withObject:sender];" Mean?

Comment: method is a NSString that has the method's name which we wanna call. we can't though since objC uses Selectors to identify method names. So we convert from string to see(ector).

Comment: with the now converted selector we tell the runtime to call this method, passing the sender as parameter